# How to show Shop by Color filter on category page Claue theme Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, category-filter

I am using Magento 2 and facing issue to show Shop by Color filter. I am using Claue theme. I checked for the **Use in Layered Navigation** option inside Store > Attribites > Product > Color. The option is set to **NO** but it should be **Filterable (with results)**. When i edit the Color attribute and set **Use in Layered Navigation** as **Filterable (with results)** inside **Storefront Properties** tab then it won't update.

I tried to find out setting in the theme options but not found anything.

Can anyone help me to get this working as earlier the filters were coming on the site.

Comment: Try reindex and test again.

Comment: Re-index is for the frontend I think so, but the attribute is not updating in the admin panel. But I tried this and nothing happened.